# How to center text in tkinter labels like Microsoft Word centered typing mode

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I am trying to make a page to page system on tkinter, however having the text starting from the right onwards looks a little peculiar and I would prefer it if the text spread out evenly from the center of the label. 
An example
`This is some really cool text`
`<< Prev . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . >> Next`

To then become

`. . . . . . . . . . . . .. This is some really cool text`
`<< Prev . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . >> Next`
The dots are there because Stackoverflow does not allow more than one space so Just ignore those. It should look just like Microsoft Word's centered writing

Here is the basic code I have, I tried using `anchor = CENTER` but that did not work as intended. Sorry if this is basic I'm new to Tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
introText = ["Some say","That it is","very important","to clean","your hands","Yababababa doooooooo"]
currentPage = 1
def forceSize(main, width, height):
    main.minsize(width, height)
    main.maxsize(width, height)
def storyGUI(textList):
    global currentPage
    textListLength = len(textList)
    def prevPage(main, textLabel):
        global currentPage
        if currentPage != 1:
            textLabel.config(text = introText[currentPage-2])
            main.title("Page "+str(currentPage-1))
            currentPage -= 1
    def nextPage(main, textLabel):
        global currentPage
        if currentPage != textListLength:
            textLabel.config(text = introText[currentPage])
            main.title("Page "+str(currentPage+1))
            currentPage += 1
    storyTK = Tk()
    forceSize(storyTK, 400, 100)
    storyTK.title("Page 1")
    textLabel = Label(storyTK, text = introText[0], font = ("Calibri", 13), anchor = CENTER)
    prevButton = Button(storyTK, text = "<< Prev", command = lambda: prevPage(storyTK, textLabel))
    nextButton = Button(storyTK, text = "Next >>", command = lambda: nextPage(storyTK, textLabel))
    textLabel.place(x = 160, y = 15)
    prevButton.place(x = 30, y = 60)
    nextButton.place(x = 310, y = 60)
    storyTK.mainloop()
#def intro():
storyGUI(introText)
```

Comment: if you use `place()` then widget Label doesn't use full size of window and it has no place to center text. You would have to set width in Label to have more space for text and then you can center. Or use `pack()` or `grid()` which can automatically resize widget to window size. And then you can center text in widget. BTW: use background color in label `bg="red"` and you will see that Label doesn't have place to center text.

Comment: @furas: `place` also has the ability to automatically resize the width and height to match the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley good to know - I never used `place()`. Meanwhile I also checked `place()` on effbot.org :) @Jeff see on effbot.org: [place()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), [pack()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [grid()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: Change `textLabel.place(x = 160, y = 15)` to  `textLabel.place(relx=0.5, y=15, anchor='center')` then it will work like you want.

Comment: Probat, Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default text for a tk label is centered inside the label so the issue here was that the label itself was not being centered.

The origin point for place is the upper most left corner x=0, y=0. Using `textLabel.place(relx=0.5, y=15, anchor='center')` centers the label widget on the master window. `relx=0` is the left edge of the window and `relx=1.0` is the right edge of the window so `relx=0.5` is the center of the window. `relx=0.5, y=15` means make a point in the center of the window down 15 pixels from the top of the window. The left edge of the label widget is placed at that point so `anchor='center'` means you center the label widget over the point.